# Crystal Reports Suppress all of list if any record has less than zero

Tags: c#, sql, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report which get all the ready orders,this report has a details section which has many of records of that ready orders with common value of (order ID) and has a parameters called (QTY) i need Suppress all these records of every order if any record of it has in (QTY) < 0 
please help..???

Comment: Your question may become more easier to understand for others to help you out if you could add more information. eg, pieces of codes where you hit a roadblock. I recommend you to check this out in case you have not done it so: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.orderid = t.orderid and
                        t2.qty < 0
                 );
```

You can also express this using window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, min(qty) over (partition by orderid) as min_qty
      from t
     ) t
where min_qty >= 0;
```

If your source is not a table but a complicated query, this is definitely a better approach because the query is evaluated only once.

Comment: i need all the data to be selected for another task , want this report to display only what i need after filtration the data ?!

Comment: @AhmedNadi . . . I don't understand your comment.  Both these queries return the rows that you need (although the second one does add an additional column, which you would simply not select in the outer query).